# Is there any way to launch jupyter notebook Quickly?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to launch jupyter notebook As soon as possible, not in the way typing 'jupyter notebook' at folder's domain.

Is there any way that i can make shortcut file to launch the jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

fastest way is to give jupyter notebook an alias.

I use Alfred on the Mac, and all I have to do is open finder with CMD+Space and type >j to open jupyter notebook, since I gave it an alias of j.

Answer (score 0):

For **Mac OS** users.

There is an Automator script can open it with just right-clicking the file and select *Open ipynb* in Quick Actions.

[Github link](https://github.com/JunsW/FastJN)

[image]